# PrismJS with React : using babel-plugin-prismjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, syntax-highlighting, prismjs

I recently decided to use PrismJS with React and to avoid import repetitions I managed to use this babel-plugin-prismjs package in order to load plugins, languages and so on.

As indicated in the plugin documentation, I've created a .babelrc file located in my root folder :

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["prismjs", {
        "languages": [
          "applescript",
          "css",
          "javascript",
          "markup",
          "scss"
        ],
        "plugins": ["line-numbers"],
        "theme": "twilight",
        "css": true
    }]
  ]
```

But I found that this file seemed to be ignored, as nothing is loaded and when console-logging my imported Prism object I'm only seeing syntax highlighting for the default languages.

The file where I want to get syntax highlighting have an `import Prism from 'prismjs'` statement and `Prism.highlightAll()`

So yes I can keep importing manually plugins, theme and languages in each of my files but I would want to find the reason of such an issue.

Thank you !

Comment: Yes, the file is ignored for me too. But I can't even get the default languages to work. I followed this article but can't figure out what is the issue as no errors. https://betterstack.dev/blog/code-highlighting-in-react-using-prismjs/

Answer (score 3):

You're halfway there. You still need to import `prismjs` somewhere, usually in your `app.js` file, and then call `Prism.highlightAll()` in the appropriate file of the page you want syntax highlighting on.

My process was as follows:

1. Setup my `.babelrc.js` file:

```js
const env = require('./env-config')

module.exports = {
  presets: ['next/babel'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'transform-define',
      env,
    ],
    [
      'prismjs', {
        'languages': ['javascript', 'css', 'html', 'jsx'],
        'plugins': ['line-numbers', 'show-language', 'copy-to-clipboard'],
        'theme': 'tomorrow',
        'css': true
      },
    ]
  ],
}
```

2. Import `prismjs` into my `_app.js` file (since I'm using Next.js, but with React, you would import this into our `app.js` file:

```js
// ...
import 'prismjs'

// ...
```

3. Use the `prismjs` API to call the `.highlightAll()` method on your desired page(s):

```js
function usePrismHighlightAll() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll()
  }, [])
}

export default function Page () {
  usePrismHighlightAll()

  // ...
}
```

As a sidenote,

could also move the `usePrismHighlightAll()` hook somewhere into your `app.js` file so that you could enable syntax highlighting in all your pages if that would save you from recalling the hook in several locations.
However, I tried doing this, and unfortunately, *it did not work in Next.js*:

```js
/* DO NOT USE THIS CODE NEXT.JS AS IT DOES NOT WORK */
import 'prismjs'

// ...

function usePrismHighlightAll() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll()
  }, [])
}

export default function App ({ Component, pageProps }) {
  usePrismHighlightAll()

  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Header />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
/* DO NOT USE THIS CODE NEXT.JS AS IT DOES NOT WORK */
```

So, stick with the process I outlined in steps 1-3.
Tthat worked for me to enable syntax highlighting on the first load of the page, let me know if this works for you.